# Trazer resultados mais antigos com Long Polling

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou criando um sistema e eu quero que ele traga todos os resultados já gravados no banco, mas ele só retorna os dados gravados a partir do momento em que atualizo a página, por exemplo se eu inserir 10 registros no banco, os 10 irão aparecer no momento em que estou na página, mas quando atualizo, todos somem!

No banco tenho uma tabela chamada `longpolling` e as colunas `id`, `notificacao` (`varchar(200)`), e `timestamp` (do tipo timestamp).

### Script PHP do Long Polling:

```
<?php
$timestart = time();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=longpolling', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST['timestamp'])){
    $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
}else{
    $pega_time = $pdo->prepare("SELECT NOW() as now");
    $pega_time->execute();
    $row = $pega_time->fetchObject();

    $timestamp = $row->now;
}

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM notificacoes WHERE timestamp > '$timestamp'");


$newData = false;
$notificacoes = array();

while(!$newData && (time()-$timestart)<20){
    $sql->execute();

    while($row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $notificacoes = $row;
        $newData = true;
    }

    usleep(500000);
}

$pega_time = $pdo->prepare("SELECT NOW() as now");
$pega_time->execute();
$row = $pega_time->fetchObject();

$timestamp = $row->now;
$data = array('notificacoes' => $notificacoes, 'timestamp' => $timestamp);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

### Script Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    pegaNotificacoes();
});

function pegaNotificacoes(timestamp){
    var data = {};
    if(typeof timestamp != 'undefined') {
        data.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    $.post('longpolling.php', data, function(res){

        for(i in res.notificacoes){
            $('#resultados').append(res.notificacoes[i].notificacao+'<br>')
        }

        pegaNotificacoes(res.timestamp);
    }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: O que CSS e HTML tem haver com o problema?

Comment: `echo json_encode($data);` retorna apenas o ultimo resultado da query? Ou é outro tipo de informação? Você quer que `SELECT * FROM notificacoes WHERE timestamp > '$timestamp'` retorne todos resultados pelo Ajax?

Comment: Ao utilizar `$notificacoes = $row;` você está substituindo as notificacões anteriores, mas ainda assim, ao menos uma notificação deveria ser retornada...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento exatamente, quero que traga todos os resultados contidos na tabela.

Comment: @Oeslei ele só retorna a partir do momento em que eu incluo um registro novo no banco, se eu incluir 10 no momento em que estou na página ele irá retornar os 10, mas se eu atualizar, todos somem!

Comment: Seu comentário deixou as coisas um pouco confusas. Na pergunta você disse que os resultados só são retornados ao atualizar a página e no comentário você disse que eles só retornam via polling.

Comment: Verdade @Oeslei, adicionei ao final da pergunta o que realmente acontece, então é via Polling que os registros estão sumindo da página.

Comment: @DavidDamasceno O seu problema não está no script do polling... Talvez você esteja considerando o `$timestamp = time();` no seu script que exibe as notificações ao acessar a página e como as notificações já são mais antigas que o `time` atual, elas não serão exibidas. Inclua seu outro script também para podermos analisar melhor.

Comment: @Oeslei estou utilizando apenas estes dois arquivos em meus estudos, teria alguma solução para o problema?

Comment: Uma solução é adicionar um script para obter todas as notificações pendentes **antes** de iniciar o long polling.

Comment: Ok, obrigado, tentarei implementar.